# JSDoc how to add member to type without creating new typedef

Tags: sequelize.js, jsdoc

Supposedly I have a type called A and B

```
/** 
 * @typedef A
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {String} name this is name A
 * @property {String} child_id this is id B
 */

/** 
 * @typedef B
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {Number} qty this is qty B
 */
```

Is there anyway I can have something like

```
{
   id:"a",
   name:"a",
   B:{
     id: "b",
     qty:0
   }
}
```

without rewriting typedef?

I have a function returning Sequelize Object thats why

Answer (score 1):

in the end what I did is using & keyword to intersect

```
/** 
 * @typedef A
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {String} name this is name A
 * @property {String} child_id this is id B
 */

/** 
 * @typedef B
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {Number} qty this is qty B
 */
```

I can say in my definition

```
@returns {A & { B : B }}
```

or creating new typedef

```
/** 
 * @typedef C
 * @type {object}
 * @property {A & {B:B}} B inside A relation
 */
```

Comment: The `&` operator is TypeScript, and is [not valid in vanilla JSDoc](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1199).  If it solves your problem, great, but JSDoc tooling that does not use TypeScript will error on this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

From my reading of your question it sounds like you can solve it by amending the typedef for `A` like so, given the expected output object you provided.

```
/** 
 * @typedef A
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {String} name this is name A
 * @property {B} type B
 */

/** 
 * @typedef B
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id 
 * @property {Number} qty 
 */
```

Unless you need a field that specific references the id of the child `B` object? And you don't want to explicitly define the child `B` relationship for some reason. In that case you could do this and specify `B` as optional.

```
/** 
 * @typedef A
 * @type {object}
 * @property {String} id this is id A
 * @property {String} name this is name A
 * @property {String} idOfB - A string that holds the id from B
 * @property {B} [B] - Notice the square brackets, this makes it an optional property.
 */
```

Here is what the resulting JSDoc looks like when VSCode provides type assistance

[image]

Comment: Oh, a nice idea for this.
but actually I would like to write that it will return B not optional

extending typedef is prefered

Comment: Ah I was silly enough to not notice same problem appears on github
https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1199